# how to transform pairwise dependence to multiway tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

For instance, there is following dependences:
A<--B, C<--H, B<--F, B<--G, A<--C, A<--D, A<--E
I want to transform these dependences to a multi-way tree like this:

```
      A
   / /  \ \
  B  C   D E
 /\ /
F G H
```

Would anyone have a good method?

Comment: How are those dependences represented? an array of pairs/tuples?

Comment: I sorry I didn't make myself clearly. These dependences represented by two arrays, one is [A, C, B, A, A, A], the other is [B, H, F, G, C, D, E].

Answer (score 0):

A solution in python.

Every dependency will is an edge from a child to his parent, e.g. `A <- B` means that the node `B` is the child of the node `A`, and that you have an edge from `B` to `A`.
That being said, you need a data structure to store those nodes and edges.

## Plain old dict

The first solution is a simple dict. Let's go.

First, you have to parse your dependencies in a usable format. I propose a format (parent, child) and a list comprehension to parse the string (*this is easy to translate in any high level language*):

```
def get_deps(dep_strings):
    """Return  list of tuples (parent, child). Very rudimentary."""
    return [tuple(dep_list) for dep_string in dep_strings.split(",") for dep_list in [dep_string.strip().split("<--")]]
```

Second, you have to iterate over the dependencies to build the tree (*this is the heart of the algorithm and is easy to translate in any high level language*):

```
def parse_to_dict(dep_strings):
    deps = get_deps(dep_strings)
    # the dict will take associate to every parent its "children dictionaries"
    d = {}
    for (p, c) in deps:
        if p not in d: # parent has not yet been seen
            d[p] = {}
        if c not in d: # child has not yet been seen
            d[c] = {} # child is a leaf, until it becomes possibly a parent
        d[p][c] = d[c] # hang the child to its parent.

    # the dict has a key for every node, and the value is its "children dictonaries".
    # usually, we don't need this direct access, thus we remove all non root elements
    for _, c  in deps:
        del d[c]

    return d
```

### Python specific

Since creating an empty dict for every unkown node is cumbersome, you can use `defaultdict` or `dict.setdefault` to make it more readable..

```
...
d = defaultdict(dict) # will create an empty dict for every missing key
for (p, c) in deps:
    d[p][c] = d[c] # hang the child to its parent, create dicts on demand.
```

Or

```
...
d = {}
for (p, c) in deps:
    d.setdefault(p, {}) # will create an empty dict if this key is missiing
    d.setdefault(c, {})
    d[p][c] = d[c] # hang the child to its parent, create dicts on demand.
```

Note that `dict.setdefault` is more flexible, since it can accept arguments, as you will see later.

## Custom tree

If you want to build a custom tree, you have to create a `Node` class, for instance:

```
class Node():
    """A very simple node class"""
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.__id = id
        self.__children = []

    def add(self, n):
        self.__children.append(n)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.__children:
            return "Node {} [{}]".format(self.__id, ", ".join(str(c) for c in self.__children))
        else:
            return "Leaf {}".format(self.__id)
```

Creating the tree will be a simple as with a dictionary:

```
...
# we still need a dict
d = {}
for (p, c) in deps:
    d.setdefault(p, Node(p)) # we need to build a node with an id,
    d.setdefault(c, Node(c)) #  hence defaultdict is not the right tool
    d[p].add(d[c])
```

## Ouput of the different methods

```
# dict
{'A': {'B': {'F': {}, 'G': {}}, 'C': {'H': {}}, 'D': {}, 'E': {}}}
# defaultdict
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
            {'A': {'B': {'F': {}, 'G': {}}, 'C': {'H': {}}, 'D': {}, 'E': {}}})
# dict.setdefault
{'A': {'B': {'F': {}, 'G': {}}, 'C': {'H': {}}, 'D': {}, 'E': {}}}
# Node
Node A [Node B [Leaf F, Leaf G], Node C [Leaf H], Leaf D, Leaf E]
```